# Custom sort to preserve order of referenced nodes

Tags: theming, views

I have a node type that references other nodes. When viewing node of Content Type A, I have set up a view that displays all references to nodes of Content Type B on a gmap.

This is the code from a template file that overrides the display of view_one; it calls the map in from another view.

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_view('view_one');
  $view->set_arguments(array($fields['nid']->raw));
  $view->execute();
  $contents = $view->result;

  foreach($contents as $content) {
    $nodes[] = $content->node_field_data_field_B_content_nid;
  }

  if (isset($nodes)) {
    $args = implode(',' , $nodes);
    $view = views_get_view('linked_map');
    $view->set_display('map');
    $view->set_arguments(array($args));
    $view->execute();

    $markup_map = $view->render($args);

  }
  else {
    $markup_map = '';
  }
?>
```

It displays beautifully. The only problem is I want to use numbered markers, so that the list is in the same order as the referenced nodes in the main view ("view_one"). Is there some way that I can either utilize a "sort" that won't rearrange the list, or write a custom sort that will preserve the existing order?

I am using the Views module version 7.x-3.1.

Comment: what order is it finally being displayed in?

Comment: It is displaying by date created I believe, just as a default if I remove all sorting criteria

Answer (score 1):

[Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) will let you define your own manual sort, and keep it consistent across different displays.